Why `arr.push(hash)` replacing old values
Facing a weird problen in ruby. Please refer following snippet.
@items_list = []

params[:items].each do |item|
  status, item_data, _status_code = get_item_details(item[:item_code])
  @items_list << item_data if status # item_data is a ruby hash
end

@items_list

get_item_details(item) returning data and with pattern matching, status gets a boolean value, item_data receives a {name: 'device', price: 90 }.
But, at the end Array(@items_list) has last inserted value the times data is inserted. This is unexpected behaviour for an array.

"get_item_details(item) returning data" – your example code contains a different expression. Do you pass item or item[:item_code]? Please fix or clarify. If @items_list contains the same value multiple time, it's probably because item_data is identical on each iteration.

"with pattern matching ..." – that's array decomposition during assignment. Ruby's pattern matching syntax looks very different.

You're iterating over params[:items] but instead of passing item you're passing get_item_details(item[:item_code]).
A less redundant way of writing this would be:
@items_list = params[:items].filter_map do |item|
  status, item_data = get_item_details(item) # last variable is not used anyways
  item_data if status 
end

Note that I don't actually know what your get_item_details method does. This is just the obvious problem with the code.

get_item_details(item) returning data and with pattern matching, status gets a boolean value, item_data gets a {name: 'device', price: 90 }

@Kamesh that's the kind of stuff you should be adding to the question itself. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Yeah but not really. You added a crappy description of the method instead of an actual complete example which people can run. Read the article I linked.

status, item_data = get_item_details(item) would also work

@Alex good suggestion.
